# html5 background video with sticky header on chrome

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-video

Im creating a web page using a JQUERY plugin (Bigvideo) that plays a video in the background.
The issue im having is that the div messes up my sticky header. The header simply does not stick after adding the video background.

The interesting thing is that it works fine on firefox. In chrome you can see that there are some more issues that are hard to describe(images and backgrounds mess up when the content tooltip appears and while scrolling)

I have tried 2 different plugins - Bigvideo and Jquery video background plugin.

The interesting thing is that when I change the z-index of the background video from -1 to 0 it works fine but it makes all my content disappear even if I change they're z-index to an positive number.

Im attaching a link to the page in construction.

Appreciate any help in this matter.

Thanks

[video background page](http://bit.ly/1bojLWB)

Comment: in Chrome Canary it displays ok, so you wait a few weeks and it solves your problem

Comment: But it means that our site will be displayed fine only on the latest chrome version. I would like to make our site visible for at last the 2-3 latest versions of chrome. Is there a way to find the specific problem that causes this issue?

Comment: The video in the background layer... you may try to place there an animated gif or nothing. In a similar case I could solve the problem with bringing the front layer to a display: fixed div but I don't know if it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your z-index is messing up with CSS files of jQuery plugins you referred to.

Comment: I tried removing all css includes to the page and I still got this issue. That was my first assumption that there were includes messing up one each other.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I had to add position:relative and z-index values to each div in my code. After that I changed the z-index of the background video to 0 instead of -1. It worked...